# Problem with setState ReactJS, done in todoList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, task

Hello i have problem about change state after onClick with this function i dont know why this is doesnt work because console.log displayed difference value and i dont know why i cant set the same state.

```
`doneUndone = (index) => {
      console.log(!this.state.scores[index].done)
      const test = !this.state.scores[index].done
      this.setState({
           scores: test,
    })
}`
```

here will be all code of this aplication  https://codepen.io/RetupK/pen/xxKmELd?editors=0010

Comment: What you're doing is assigning the boolean value to the scores, where scores is a array. you need to change the done value of the particular todo and update the state with new scores. 

I've added code as answer change your doneUndone method and you'll be good to go.

Comment: It looks like `scores` is an array but you're completely overwriting it with a boolean. You need to update the score only at _that index_ (there are a number of ways you can achieve this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your state scores is an array and in your method of done you are assigning Boolean value to it where as it must be an array itself. Because you're using .map() in your render method which only works with array not boolean.

What you need to do is change the done property of particular object in scores and pass the newly updated scores object to setState method and it will work.

```
  doneUndone = (index) => {
        this.state.scores[index].done = !this.state.scores[index].done
        this.setState({
            scores: this.state.scores,
        }) 
  }
```

Comment: how can i do it?

Comment: There will be a tick option (True or Right sign) click on it and it will be green in color

Comment: there is a transparent tick below the down arrow click it

Comment: oh nice, done i am new here and i dont know all options ;p

Comment: Actually this means that the answer given is true and the one who has asked the question got the solution from this answer so that he's marking it true/accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `this.state` to get previously done value you might have problems when you fire `doneUndone` method multiple times (e.g. clicking button few times in a row). That's why I suggest such solution:

```
doneUndone = index => {
  this.setState(state => ({
    scores: state.scores.map((score, idx) =>
      idx === index ? { ...score, done: !score.done } : score
    )
  }));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `doneUndone` method isn't updating the state properly. You can check the method form here.

```
  doneUndone = (index) => {
    const score = this.state.scores[index];
    const updatedScore = {...score, done: !score.done};
    const updatedScores = [...this.state.scores];
    updatedScores[index] = updatedScore;
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        scores: updatedScores
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  doneUndone = (index) => {


        let modScores = this.state.scores;
         modScores[index].done=!this.state.scores[index].done

        this.setState({
            scores: modScores
        })

    }
```

**cleaner way to do it**

Comment: Why to use another variable. directly use this.state.scores

Comment: ya we can i did not see your answer,nice